# Cloudwatch metric filter sees event, but alarm doesn't fire

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have set up a Cloudwatch Metric to watch a log file:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "log_errors" {
  name = "${local.fullname}-log-errors"
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/${local.fullname}"
  pattern = "{ $._logLevel = \"error\" }"
  metric_transformation {
    name = "${local.fullname}-error-count"
    namespace = "MyApp"
    value     = "1"
  }
}
```

I can see the metric is working - note the dot at 13:15 below (me manually creating a log entry to test):

[image]

And an alarm to fire if the metric reports 1 or more events within a minute:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "log_errors_alarm" {
  alarm_name        = "${local.fullname}-log-errors"
  alarm_description = "log.error() count for MyApp lambda ${local.fullname}"
  metric_name         = "${local.fullname}-error-count"
  threshold           = "0"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  unit                = "Count"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  datapoints_to_alarm = "1"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  period    = "60"
  namespace = "MyApp"
  treat_missing_data = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions      = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.sns_topic_arn.value]
  ok_actions         = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.sns_topic_arn.value]
}
```

But despite the metric having an event (per above) the alarm is never fired:

[image]

[image]

I'm unsure how to debug this, as all the AWS resources are created successfully, errors that I create manually are passed to the metric, and I'm using a very similar alarm config in other lambdas successfully, where it throws alarms.

**Why is my metric working but my alarm not alarming?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put my money on the Unit being inconsistent between the `metric_alarm` and `metric_filter`.

You're setting the `unit` on the `metric_alarm` to be `Count`, but you're not setting a `unit` on the `metric_filter`'s `metric_transformation`, so the `metric_transformation` will default to `None`.

Try setting the `unit` in the alarm to `None` or removing `unit` altogether.

Comment: Thanks @Dejan, this was exactly the cause of the problem - removing the `unit` (so the values are consistent) makes the alarm fire. Sorry about the wait - I was on holiday and couldn't test it. I've edited your answer a little to make it clearer too, hope that was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have something very similar set up that is working & would try this. Update: Looking at it more closely, I believe you should be using `comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"` not `comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"`

```
metric_transformation {
    name = "${local.fullname}-error-count"
    namespace = "MyApp"
    value     = "1"
    default_value = "0"
  }
```

and

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "log_errors_alarm" {
  alarm_name        = "${local.fullname}-log-errors"
  alarm_description = "log.error() count for MyApp lambda ${local.fullname}"
  metric_name         = "${local.fullname}-error-count"
  threshold           = "1"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  #unit                = "Count"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  #datapoints_to_alarm = "1"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  period    = "60"
  namespace = "MyApp"
  treat_missing_data = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions      = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.sns_topic_arn.value]
  ok_actions         = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.sns_topic_arn.value]
}
```

Both `unit` & `datapoint_to_alarm` are optional parameters. Try excluding those. I assume both resources `cloudwatch_log_metric_filter` & `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` are using the same local variables. Since you did not post all of your `cloudwatch_log_metric_filter` parameters, I imagine your `pattern = ""` is what it should be.

Comment: But `threshold` in my configuration is `0` - `GreaterThanThreshold` should mean anything above 0 triggers the alarm.

Comment: valid point. Try setting threshold to 1 in this case, just for comparison purposes, if anything. I've updated threshold in my example to properly reflect this.