# AWS eventbridge event and cloudwatch metric filter won't trigger alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I'm looking for specific patterns in user behavior to raise alarms. One of which is when someone creates or deletes a subnet in AWS.

EventBridge Pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateRouteTable",
      "DeleteRouteTable",
      "ReplaceRouteTableAssociation"
    ]
  }
}
```

My Eventbridge pattern shows up in my CloudWatch Log Groups. Here is my metric filter:

```
{ $.eventName = "CreateRouteTable" || $.eventName = "DeleteRouteTable" || $.eventName = "ReplaceRouteTableAssociation") }
```

An example payload I'm getting from EventBridge into my target Cloudwatch log stream when I create a route table is below:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "8b6c8639-2569-09da-8f6a-3b6fbaf72ef1",
    "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "ACCOUNT_ID",
    "time": "2024-01-28T01:30:33Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "eventVersion": "1.09",
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": "Root",
            "principalId": "ACCOUNT_ID",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root",
            "accountId": "ACCOUNT_ID",
            "accessKeyId": "ASIA****************",
            "sessionContext": {
                "attributes": {
                    "creationDate": "2024-01-27T23:09:14Z",
                    "mfaAuthenticated": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        "eventTime": "2024-01-28T01:30:33Z",
        "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "CreateRouteTable",    # <--- What I'm looking for
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "8.8.8.8",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0",
        "requestParameters": {
```

But Nothing shows up in my custom metric and therefore no alarm is triggered. I'm fairly convinced it's my metric filter or setting, but need a little guidance. For completion sake, I'm using the AWS CLI and below are the commands I issue it in Bash:

```
#################################
### Create/delete route table ###
#################################
SNS_TOPIC_ARN="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudWatch-Alerts"
CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME=/aws/events/aws-cis-security-alerts
CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAMESPACE="CISSecurityAlerts"
PROFILE=root
EVENT_BRIDGE_RULE_NAME="route-table-create-or-delete" 
CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_FILTER_NAME=CreateOrDeleteRouteTable
CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAME=CreateOrDeleteRouteTable
CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_NAME="Create or delete route tables"
CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_DESCRIPTION="Route table additions/deletions"

# Create EventBridge rule to detect events
aws events put-rule --name $EVENT_BRIDGE_RULE_NAME \
    --profile $PROFILE \
    --event-pattern '{
        "source": ["aws.ec2"],
        "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
        "detail": {
            "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
            "eventName": ["CreateRouteTable", 
                          "DeleteRouteTable", 
                          "ReplaceRouteTableAssociation"]
        }
    }'

# Create EventBridge target with newly create CloudWatch log group
aws events put-targets --rule $EVENT_BRIDGE_RULE_NAME \
    --profile $PROFILE \
    --targets '[
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Arn": "'"$LOG_GROUP_ARN"'"
}]'

# Create CloudWatch metric namespace/name
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data \
    --metric-name "$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAME" \
    --namespace "$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAMESPACE" \
    --value 1 \
    --profile "$PROFILE"

# Add a metric filter onto the cloudwatch log group for tracking events
aws logs put-metric-filter \
    --profile $PROFILE \
    --log-group-name $CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME \
    --filter-name $CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_FILTER_NAME \
    --filter-pattern '{ 
        ($.eventName = "CreateRouteTable" ||
        $.eventName = "DeleteRouteTable" ||
        $.eventName = "ReplaceRouteTableAssociation")
    }' \
    --metric-transformations '{
        "metricName": "'"$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAME"'",
        "metricNamespace": "'"$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAMESPACE"'",
        "metricValue": "$.detail.eventName"
    }'

# Create Cloudwatch Alarm
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm \
    --alarm-name "$CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_NAME" \
    --actions-enabled \
    --alarm-actions "$SNS_TOPIC_ARN" \
    --metric-name "$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAME" \
    --namespace "$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAMESPACE" \
    --statistic Sum \
    --period 300 \
    --threshold 1 \
    --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold \
    --treat-missing-data notBreaching \
    --evaluation-periods 1 \
    --alarm-description "$CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_DESCRIPTION" \
    --profile "$PROFILE"
```

EDIT: Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863247/cloudwatch-metric-filter-sees-event-but-alarm-doesnt-fire?rq=2) post and tried to reconcile the unit discrepancies. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of trial and error with the metric filter settings, I found that I needed to set a default value of 0 in the metric transformations section:

```
aws logs put-metric-filter \
    --profile $PROFILE \
    --log-group-name $CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME \
    --filter-name $CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_FILTER_NAME \
    --filter-pattern '{ 
        $.eventName = "CreateRouteTable" ||
        $.eventName = "DeleteRouteTable" ||
        $.eventName = "ReplaceRouteTableAssociation"
    }' \
    --metric-transformations '{
        "metricName": "'"$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAME"'",
        "metricNamespace": "'"$CLOUDWATCH_METRIC_NAMESPACE"'",
        "metricValue": "'"$.detail.eventName"'",
        "defaultValue": 0  # <-- NEEDED TO ADD THIS
    }'
```

The alarms now go off upon creation or deletion of a subnet. What I'm missing to this answer is the *why* this is needed for the alarm to work.